# NHibernate insert into a many-to-many collection for multiple objects without querying

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, hql

Let's say i have this data model:

```
public class User {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<User> TrackingUsers { get; set; }
  public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

and this mapping:

```
    public VehicleMap()
    {
        Table("Vehicles");

        Map(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Category);            

        HasManyToMany(x => x.TrackingUsers)
                    .AsSet()
                    .Table("UsersToVehicles")
                    .LazyLoad()
                    .ParentKeyColumn("VehicleId")
                    .ChildKeyColumn("UserId");
    }

    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");

        Map(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }

    public CategoryMap()
    {
        Table("Categories");

        Map(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Vehicles);
    }
```

Each vehicle can be placed only in one category but can be tracked by several users and each user can track several vehicles.

What i want to achieve is to allow user to set 'tracking' status for all vehicles in category.
That means for each vehicle in category i need to add `User` instance into `TrackingUsers` collection.

Obviously I don't want to query all vehicles in selected category. Are there any HQL or criteria queries to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with HQL or Criteria, but you should be able to do this with native sql.

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(@"INSERT INTO UsersToVehicles (VehicleId, UserId)
                         SELECT VehicleId, :userId 
                         FROM Vehicles WHERE CategoryId = :categoryId")
       .SetInt32("userId", userId)
       .SetInt32("categoryId", categoryId)
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

But instead of doing this consider adding TrackingUsers relation between user and category. This will allow to automatically track newly added vehicles to a category.